# How to evaluate $\int[(\frac{x}{2})^x + (\frac{2}{x})^x]\log_2x\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

This integral appeared in my exam but I couldn't solve it within the time limits (~2 minutes)  $$I = \int\left[\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^x + \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^x\right]\log_2x \mathrm dx$$

A) $\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^x + \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^x$

B) $\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^x -\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^x$

C) $\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^x\log_2x$

D) $\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^x\log_x2$

E) $\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^x\log_x2$

F) $\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^x\log_2x$

I observed that the first two terms in addition are reciprocal. However, I got failed by trying substitution techniques ( like $t = (\frac{x}{2})^x$) and integration by parts is making it more messy. Can you give a hint/solution (like a proper substitution or method) to solve this ?
Thanks !

Comment: If you were supposed to solve that in 2 minutes, my initial guess would be applying some type of clever IBP or Reverse Product Rule. Just a thought.

Comment: @Accelerator Thanks but What is reverse product rule ? Are you talking about applying IBP more than once ? But the integrand makes it horrible and time consuming :(

Comment: It is [This](https://math.libretexts.org/Under_Construction/Purgatory/Book%3A_Active_Calculus_(Boelkins_et_al.)/05%3A_Finding_Antiderivatives_and_Evaluating_Integrals/5.04%3A_Integration_by_Parts#:~:text=Reversing%20the%20Product%20Rule%3A%20Integration%20by%20Parts,-Problem%20(c)%20in&text=f(x)g(x)%3D%E2%88%ABf(,%E2%80%B2(x)dx.&text=%E2%88%ABf(x)g%E2%80%B2,%E2%80%B2(x)dx.&text=and%20thus%20we%20can%20state,v%E2%88%92%E2%88%ABvdu.), which is essentially part of the IBP theorem.

Comment: @Accelerator Thanks.

Comment: @Accelerator Can you please write an answer? I have seen that you write many integration answers and questions.

Comment: I want to, but unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve that (assuming your exam didn't make a typo).

Comment: @Accelerator Ok thanks. I will add the options too which were given as answers to this question.

Comment: An easier integral is$$\int\left[\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^x+\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^x\right]\left(\ln\frac{x}{2}+1\right)dx=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^x-\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^x+C.$$Since $\ln\frac{x}{2}=(\log_2x-1)\ln2$, the given problem reduces to $\int\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\pm x}dx$, which standard functions can't do. I look forward to the posted "answers" you could choose between. (Multiple-choice integration has the assessment downside it allows you to just differentiate the choices.)

Comment: I just differentiated all the possible choices. None of them return the original integrand.

Comment: @J.G. Please see the options I have added. It is very related to what you wrote. Thanks

Comment: @Accelerator I am sorry then. I think there was a typo then in my exam as suggested by J.G.

Comment: That's fine! It didn't take long for me to differentiate them anyways. You might want to bring this up to whoever wrote the exam by linking them to this post.

Comment: @Accelerator Ok. But I'm still not very sure if it's a typo. I'll update soon. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Broooo yesterdays jee question...i skipped this one

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman Yes. I too skipped. But how do you know ? Does JEE also conducts in America ?

Comment: @An_Elephant I too wasted 5 minutes on this question, differentiating all the parts didn't give any answer. I also thought of asking this here.

Comment: hi is this from 8th april shift 2??

Comment: @user1157207 Yes

Comment: ah i was in the same shift too, and turns out this ques is wrong, its a bonus, i wasted so much time in the exam bruh btw how was the paper

Comment: @user1157207 It didn't went well, worse than Jan attempt. I hope your paper have gone well :)

Comment: thanks for asking, january, mine went okayish, this time ill get 99.6, hope your advance goes well, also about your question where you asked about proving that integral, which book did you get it from?

Comment: @user1157207 99.6 is okayish to you . Anyway, all the best for advanced. That question was given by a teacher for fun and challenge.

Comment: @An_Elephant How did advance go for you?

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman Not very well. Mathematics went fine. Chemistry and physics gone wrong as I hadn't revised much.

Comment: @An_Elephant Ok dude. I really wish the best for you. Hope you get into good IIT's. By the way, I'm an Indian and I just changed my identity here simply :) . Even I wrote the exam. I'm a repeater. So I dont expect very high marks. Like I did 28 ques. Thats all I could do. Maths was the hardest for me. But I made some logical guesses and solved like around 10. Ofc matrix match was easy and a few multiple correct

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman Thanks. I also wish same for you. I attempted more question than you but with a terrible accuracy. For example, I just wrote more than 20 random numbers in 20 numerical questions because they had no negative marking lol.